# Avoiding multiples table scan in the same query repeated in subqueries (pivot table)

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, business-intelligence

I have a plain table (`db.mkt_parceiros_2`) with dates and status and I must create a pivot from it (a table with MM-YYYY in Y axis and statuses in X axis and then inside the table its correspondents values).
I'm extracting the same table seven times since it is the number of statuses and then I group it by the date and status.

It is reading seven times the same table and its taking a very long time.
I wonder if there is any way to improve its performance.
I'm trying as below:

```
select 
    result.reference_date
    ,sum(case when result.funnel_phase = 'signup_date' then cont else 0 end) as signup_date
    ,sum(case when result.funnel_phase = '01_approval_requested' then cont else 0 end) as 01_approval_requested
    ,sum(case when result.funnel_phase = '02_approval_allowed' then cont else 0 end) as 02_approval_allowed
    ,sum(case when result.funnel_phase = '03_profile_sent_documents' then cont else 0 end) as 03_profile_sent_documents
    ,sum(case when result.funnel_phase = '04_profile_approved' then cont else 0 end) as 04_profile_approved
    ,sum(case when result.funnel_phase = '05_loan_request' then cont else 0 end) as 05_loan_request
    ,sum(case when result.funnel_phase = '06_boleto_confirmed' then cont else 0 end) as 06_boleto_confirmed
    ,sum(case when result.funnel_phase = '07_loan_issued' then cont else 0 end) as 07_loan_issued
from
    (
                select 'signup_date' funnel_phase, month(signup_date) as reference_date, count(signup_date) as cont
                from db.mkt_parceiros_2
                group by 1, 2

                 union all

                select '01_approval_requested' funnel_phase, month(01_approval_requested) as reference_date, count(01_approval_requested) as cont
                from db.mkt_parceiros_2
                group by 1, 2

                union all

                select '02_approval_allowed' funnel_phase, month(02_approval_allowed) as reference_date, count(02_approval_allowed) as cont
                from db.mkt_parceiros_2
                group by 1, 2

                union all

                select '03_profile_sent_documents' funnel_phase, month(03_profile_sent_documents) as reference_date, count(03_profile_sent_documents) as cont
                from db.mkt_parceiros_2
                group by 1, 2

                union all

                select '04_profile_approved' funnel_phase, month(04_profile_approved) as reference_date, count(04_profile_approved) as cont
                from db.mkt_parceiros_2
                group by 1, 2

                union all

                select '05_loan_request' funnel_phase, month(05_loan_request) as reference_date, count(05_loan_request) as cont
                from db.mkt_parceiros_2
                group by 1, 2

                union all

                select '06_boleto_confirmed' funnel_phase, month(06_boleto_confirmed) as reference_date, count(06_boleto_confirmed) as cont
                from db.mkt_parceiros_2
                group by 1, 2

                union all

                select '07_loan_issued' funnel_phase, month(07_loan_issued) as reference_date, count(07_loan_issued) as cont
                from db.mkt_parceiros_2
                group by 1, 2
 ) result

group by result.reference_date
```

Comment: There is only one scan; all the SUMs are done i a single scan.

Comment: @RickJames When I call the same table 7 times it doesnt re-load each one of them?

Comment: The `SELECTs` in the _union_ will be "reloaded"; the `SUMs` in the `SELECT` won't.  But I am not  convinced you need the unions.

Comment: @RickJames What'd you do instead? Call the table once in CTE and work with it? Give me suggestions please.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 1):

All of these `reference_date` fields selected by the `union` subqueries return a month number.

You can construct an equivalent query, using a numbers table, that includes all 12 month values and cross joining `db.mkt_parceiros_2` to it:

```
SELECT t1.m AS reference_date,
       COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN MONTH(signup_date) = t1.m THEN 1 
             END) AS signup_date,
       COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN MONTH(01_approval_requested) = t1.m THEN 1 
             END) AS 01_approval_requested,
       ... etc
FROM (
   SELECT 1 AS m UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL
   SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL
   SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12) AS t1
CROSS JOIN db.mkt_parceiros_2 AS t2
GROUP BY t1.m
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to Giorgos', but avoids the **CROSS** JOIN; whether the expensive/complex join condition is faster than a CROSS JOIN I can't say for sure though.

```
SELECT theMonths.m AS reference_date
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(mpt.signup_date) = theMonths.m THEN 1 END) AS signup_date
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(mpt.`01_approval_requested`) = theMonths.m THEN 1 END) AS `01_approval_requested`
   , ...
FROM (
   SELECT 1 AS m 
   UNION SELECT 2 
   UNION SELECT 3
   ...) AS theMonths
LEFT JOIN db.mkt_parceiros_2 AS mpt
ON theMonths.m IN (
         MONTH(mpt.signup_date) 
         , MONTH(mpt.`01_approval_requested`)
         , ...
         )
GROUP BY theMonths.m
;
```

If you are only going for a specific year, there **might** be some performance gains from this change *... but it is unlikely as MySQL won't/can't take advantage of indexes in OR condition lists.*

```
SELECT theMonths.m AS reference_date
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN mpt.signup_date BETWEEN theMonths.mBegin AND theMonths.mEnd THEN 1 END) AS signup_date
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN mpt.`01_approval_requested` BETWEEN theMonths.mBegin AND theMonths.mEnd THEN 1 END) AS `01_approval_requested`
   , ...
FROM (
   SELECT 1 AS m, '2017-01-01' AS mBegin, '2017-01-31' AS mEnd 
   UNION SELECT 2 , '2017-02-01', '2017-02-28' /* careful of leap year */
   ...) AS theMonths
LEFT JOIN db.mkt_parceiros_2 AS mpt
   ON mpt.signup_date BETWEEN theMonths.mBegin AND theMonths.mEnd
   OR mpt.`01_approval_requested` BETWEEN theMonths.mBegin AND theMonths.mEnd
   OR ...
GROUP BY theMonths.m
;
```